# table width issues in Outlook HTML

Tags: html, css, web, outlook

I am not an UI expert, just creating a simple HTML page to display the logs from database table in outlook. couple of rows has exception details and it seems to override the table width attribute. Someone suggested me to go with inline styling and it doesn't seems to help either.

Any help would be appreciated. ( Devastated after trying of more than 100 methods)

Am I missing something. Below is the screenshot and html for your reference. [image: to]

HTML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns:tns6="http://dewa.gov.ae/SmartGrid/xsd/Logger_v1_0_0_0.xsd" xmlns:tib="http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>        

h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: black;

}







                </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>LogData</h2>
<table border="0" bgcolor="#fff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300" height="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;">UUID</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
2821d9cc-e9c4-4823-86d0-6f88944ec488</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;">InterfaceId</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
11111</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;">ApplicationName</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
adadfadsfsf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>ComponentName</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
adadfadsfsf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>SourceApplicationName</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
adadfadsfsf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>TargetApplicationName</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
adadfadsfsf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Message</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
adadfadsfsf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>EngineName</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
adadfadsfsf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>TransactionTimeStamp</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
2019-12-08T16:29:04.408&#43;04:00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>TimeStamp</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
2019-12-08T16:29:04.408&#43;04:00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Exception</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;tns:logdata xmlns:tns=&quot;http://dewa.gov.ae/SmartGrid/xsd/Logger_v1_0_0_0.xsd&quot; xmlns:tib=&quot;http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions&quot;&gt;&lt;tns:logdata&gt;&lt;tns:uuid&gt;cac7e8c7-5b76-4f54-a193-a4230c7a4ba2&lt;/tns:uuid&gt;&lt;tns:interfaceid&gt;11111&lt;/tns:interfaceid&gt;&lt;tns:applicationname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:applicationname&gt;&lt;tns:componentname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:componentname&gt;&lt;tns:sourceapplicationname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:sourceapplicationname&gt;&lt;tns:targetapplicationname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:targetapplicationname&gt;&lt;tns:message&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:message&gt;&lt;tns:enginename&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:enginename&gt;&lt;tns:transactiontimestamp&gt;2019-12-05T12:22:17.901&#43;04:00&lt;/tns:transactiontimestamp&gt;&lt;tns:timestamp&gt;2019-12-05T12:22:17.901&#43;04:00&lt;/tns:timestamp&gt;&lt;tns:logtype&gt;INFO&lt;/tns:logtype&gt;&lt;/tns:logdata&gt;&lt;/tns:logdata&gt;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>LogType</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
INFO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>EventPayload</th>
<td bgcolor="#fafafa" width="150" style="margin:0 auto;  border: 1px solid black;" align="left" height="100%">
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;tns:logdata xmlns:tns=&quot;http://dewa.gov.ae/SmartGrid/xsd/Logger_v1_0_0_0.xsd&quot; xmlns:tib=&quot;http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions&quot;&gt;&lt;tns:logdata&gt;&lt;tns:uuid&gt;cac7e8c7-5b76-4f54-a193-a4230c7a4ba2&lt;/tns:uuid&gt;&lt;tns:interfaceid&gt;11111&lt;/tns:interfaceid&gt;&lt;tns:applicationname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:applicationname&gt;&lt;tns:componentname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:componentname&gt;&lt;tns:sourceapplicationname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:sourceapplicationname&gt;&lt;tns:targetapplicationname&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:targetapplicationname&gt;&lt;tns:message&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:message&gt;&lt;tns:enginename&gt;adadfadsfsf&lt;/tns:enginename&gt;&lt;tns:transactiontimestamp&gt;2019-12-05T12:22:17.901&#43;04:00&lt;/tns:transactiontimestamp&gt;&lt;tns:timestamp&gt;2019-12-05T12:22:17.901&#43;04:00&lt;/tns:timestamp&gt;&lt;tns:logtype&gt;INFO&lt;/tns:logtype&gt;&lt;/tns:logdata&gt;&lt;/tns:logdata&gt;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<hr>
<font face="Arial" color="Black" size="1"><br>
Our Vision: A globally leading sustainable innovative corporation.<br>
<p>Our Mission: We are committed and aligned to Dubai’s 8 Principles and 50-Year Charter supporting the UAE’s directions through the delivery of global leading services and innovative energy solutions enriching lives and ensuring the happiness of our stakeholders
 in a sustainable manner.<br>
</font></p>
<hr>
<font face="Arial" color="Green" size="1"><br>
Please consider the environment before printing this email.<br>
<p></p>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `table-layout:fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

At last fixed it with below style added to `<table>` and `<td>`

```
 <table bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="auto" style="table-layout: fixed;">

<td align="left" height="100%" width="800" style="margin:5 auto;  border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;word-break:break-all;font-family:arial;font-size:8px;background-color: #f2f2f2;">
```

Comment: setting the width to "auto" at the <table> and setting the  width to desired pixels in <td> seems to have done the trick